# SpyOn and return typeof undefined object in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, jasmine

I have a script that is failing in IE8 because Date.now() is undefined. I have abstracted out Date.now() into a method and want to unit test it do I know it works when Date.now() is undefined.

```
Foo.prototype = {
  date: function() {
    // I think this works. Not sure until I get my unit test working...
    if (typeof Date.now === 'undefined') {
      Date.now = function () { return +new Date(); }
    }
    return Date.now(); // fails in IE8. Undefined.
  }
}
```

My test goes something like this

```
describe('Foo', function() {
  it('has the current date time', function() {
    // This passes
    spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(1234);
    foo = new Foo;
    expect(foo.date()).toBe(1234);
  });

  it('has the current date time for IE8', function() {
    // This won't pass
    spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(null);
    foo = new Foo;
    expect(foo.date()).toBe(1234); // TODO
  });
});
```

How do I stub out undefined? I was thinking returning an undefined method in returnValue.

I know my tests aren't polished as I have only just started working with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't spy on an undefined function.
you can do something like this:

```
  it('has the current date time for IE8', function() {
    // This won't pass
      var x = Date.now;
      Date.now = undefined;
    foo = new Foo;
    expect(foo.date()).toBe(1234); // TODO
      Date.now = x;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a spy still behaves like a function, but you're not actually calling the method when you test if it exists. When you `spyOn(Date, 'now')` you're replacing the built-in `Date.now` function with a spy object. If you did something like this:

```
describe('Foo', function() {
  describe("without a Date.now", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      this.now = Date.now;
      Date.now = undefined;
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      Date.now = this.now;
    });

    it('has the current date time for IE8', function() {
      spyOn(window, 'Date').and.returnValue(1234);
      foo = new Foo;
      expect(foo.date()).toBe(1234); // TODO
    });
  });
});
```

The `typeof` check will succeed, and your code will set the Date.now function to your new implementation. Since this isn't a jasmine spy, you have to clean up after yourself (hence the `afterEach`). This spec still doesn't quite pass because it's not stubbing the `Date` constructor quite right.